# Gridview single cell

Tags: android, gridview, view

guys i have a gridview as below

```
view 1  view 2 view 3
view 4  view 5 view 6
......
```

i have made this grid view using the below components

```
android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
android:columnWidth="90dp" 
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

i want a single grid at the bottom as

```
view 1  view 2 view 3
view 4  view 5 view 6       (FIG 2)
V I E W 7 (completely)
```

i played with all the 3 components above  but im getting a single gridrow  like

```
V I E W 1
 V I E W 2..
```

but i need as (FIG 2)

The below is the xml

```
 <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/EmptyFonesLayout" >
 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:verticalSpacing="4dp" android:horizontalSpacing="4dp" android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:columnWidth="90dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"   android:background="#ffffff"
                android:textFilterEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:columnSpan="number of columns"
```

in your xml for the 7th view

put on your xml layout file to make it more clearer also

Comment: so are you going to add the components in the code or the xml or what, you want me to put on what i would do?

Comment: i mean your using gridview, i would use tablelayout with tablerows, is this a has to be gridview thing assignment or something

Comment: i have a requirement where i need to add a view at the bottom (as shown in view 7) like a loading text (inside a layout..)since im adding the components like stretch mode n all i could not add as a complete row..

Comment: in getView i create a view which has a relativelayout inside it contains a image and a text below it ..this relative layout is passed to individual grid all the time..like in each grid i have a image and text below it..i wish i had added a picture of it.. image is in below link 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/device20121213152425.png/.
which the putline black image shows the grid individual

Comment: i still say TableLayout, Tablerows and dynamically update like that, im still a beginer but with Tablerows you can use layout_span and make view 7 take up all the columns, im still a beginer, thats all i can come up with man, sorry if im wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

stretchMode is causing this issue. as you set stretchMode to columnWidth.

As documentation says that

> stretchMode defines how columns should stretch to fill the available empty space, if any.
>   In columnWidth option Each column is stretched equally.

For more details check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3astretchMode)

I haven't tried this but try to set stretchMode as none/spacingWidth/spacingWidthUniform instead of columnWidth

```
`<GridView
       android:stretchMode="none"
 />
```

Comment: Hi thanks..but as i said i have played with all the given components..also the one you have mentioned ..but of no help..